# std::ostream & operator << using a function within my class

Tags: c++, enums, operator-keyword, ostream

So i have an ostream operator that needs to print out objects to an ostream.. Simple right. I have a print function that takes an ostream and also does this same thing. My ostream is defined as a friend in my class. I just want to know how i can utlize my print function in my operator... Also my print function uses an enum

```
void Box::print(std::ostream & out, Box::Type type) const
{
switch (type)
{
case FILLED:
    for (int i = 0; i < _height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < _width; j++)
        {
            out << "x";
        }
        out << std::endl;
    }
    break;
case HOLLOW:
    for (int i = 0; i < _height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < _width; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == _height - 1 || j == 0 || j == _width - 1)
                out << "x";
            else
                out << " ";
        }
        out << std::endl;
    }
    break;
case CHECKERED:
    for (int i = 0; i < _height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < _width; j++)
        {
            if ((i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0) || (i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 != 0))
            {
                out << "x";
            }
            else
            {
                out << " ";
            }
        }
        out << std::endl;
    }
    break;
}
}



std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &out, Box &b1)
{
   return b1.print(out, Box::Type type) // obviously dosent exist here
}
```

Comment: Instead of this chain of `if` statements you might want to use `switch`. Also why `(Type type == HOLLOW)`?

Comment: Calling a function from an overloaded operator isn't different than calling it from anywhere else.

Comment: `return b1.print(out,  FILLED);`  (or HOLLOW or whatever type you want to be invoked in this case)

Comment: Ahh yes thank you im such an idiot, also im probably going to make a switch statement instead of these if statements. Also type is an enum

Comment: @SamuelGrenon you didn't really finish answering his question. What is `if (Type type == HOLLOW)` supposed to be doing?? Ie. what are you trying to do there?

Comment: if the enum type == hollow or in this case i suppose case 0 do that. Im completely up to suggestion in fixing the problem. I havent used an enum before but i know it works similar to a switch...

Comment: Also you're mixing streams in your print function.  You've got `out` and `cout`.

Comment: Oh thats an accident i just added that last line. Im going to fix it and post it right now, but if My print function takes an enum. My ostream operator can only take an object and ostream. So how can i pass it the enum....

Comment: I've voted to close because the question is framed about `ostream` and `operator<<`, but the problem seems to be about the relation of `Box::Type` to `Box`.

Comment: Well not really. My problem is trying to get my ostream operator to use my print function. That was the problem and still is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

The first one is to add the `Type` as a member of the class and you can access it from within the operator.

The second one is to actually overload the ostream operator with std::pair.
For example:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const std::pair<Box, Type>& p) {
    p.first.print(os, p.second);
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Don’t forget to `return os;`.